# Making a new WPF window from C# class

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently have one window designed in WPF and coded in C#. I want one of my buttons to open another window, which I would also like to design in WPF. What is the best way for me to do this? Can I make multiple xaml files and call them from the same .cs class? Or should I just have one xaml file? I tried to add a new window into my xaml but it won't allow me to do that. I want all the code to be in the same C# class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple XAML files and call them from the same .cs file.

For exemple, let's say you have `Window1.xaml` and `Window2.xaml`. `Window1` is your main window, and the code behind will look like this :

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In `Window1` you have a button named `btnOpenWindow`. On click, you may do that to open `Window2` :

```
private void btnOpenWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var window = new Window2();
    window.Show();
}
```

Then a new `Window2` is opened.

However you won't be able to get events or others things coming from `Window2` in `Window1.xaml.cs`, obviously you will control that in `Window2.xaml.cs` for exemple.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the MVVM pattern in your project.
So you have different windows and just one ViewModel to handel these views and your data.

Have a look on: [MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish?rq=1)